# Yii Error: session_regenerate_id()

Tags: yii

When i try to create a user after form filling the form following errors appear. please help me in solving this:

> session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent

whats this error and how to solve this..?

Comment: can you show which line of code generates this error, and a few lines above and below it? edit your question and add them

Comment: And maybe your file with utf-8 BOM, remove BOM in utf-8 files

Answer (score 0):

use: headers_sent() to know where the headers have already been sent and correct it.